# sort unix file by id

Tags: linux, unix, sorting

I want to sort a unix file by the id column but when I use sort -k4,4 or -k4,4n I do not get the expected result.

The column of interest should be sorted like this:

```
id1
id2
id3
id4
etc.
```

Instead it is sorted like this when i do sort -k4,4

```
id1
id10
id100
id1000
id10000
id10001
etc.
```

My unix version uses the following sort function:

```
sort --help
Usage: sort [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Write sorted concatenation of all FILE(s) to standard output.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
Ordering options:

  -b, --ignore-leading-blanks  ignore leading blanks
  -d, --dictionary-order      consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters
  -f, --ignore-case           fold lower case to upper case characters
  -g, --general-numeric-sort  compare according to general numerical value
  -i, --ignore-nonprinting    consider only printable characters
  -M, --month-sort            compare (unknown) < `JAN' < ... < `DEC'
  -n, --numeric-sort          compare according to string numerical value
  -r, --reverse               reverse the result of comparisons

Other options:

  -c, --check               check whether input is sorted; do not sort
  -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]     start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
  -m, --merge               merge already sorted files; do not sort
  -o, --output=FILE         write result to FILE instead of standard output
  -s, --stable              stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
  -S, --buffer-size=SIZE    use SIZE for main memory buffer
  -t, --field-separator=SEP  use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
  -T, --temporary-directory=DIR  use DIR for temporaries, not $TMPDIR or /tmp;
                              multiple options specify multiple directories
  -u, --unique              with -c, check for strict ordering;
                              without -c, output only the first of an equal run
  -z, --zero-terminated     end lines with 0 byte, not newline
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-V` or `--version-sort` option for version sort

`sort -V -k4,4 file.txt`

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
id5
id3
id100
id1
id10
```

**Ouput:**

```
$ sort -V file.txt
id1
id3
id5
id10
id100
```

**EDIT:**

If your implementation of `sort` doesn't have the `-V` option then a work-around using `sed` to remove `id` so a numeric sort `-n` can be done and then replace `id` back with `sed`, like this:

```
sed -E 's/id([0-9]+)/\1/' file.txt | sort -n -k4,4 | sed -E 's/( *)([0-9]+)( *|$)/\1id\2\3/'
```

*Note: this solution is dependent on the data, only works if no columns containing purely numbers are found before the ID column.*

Comment: I tried it but I get an error: sort: invalid option -- V
Try `sort --help' for more information.

Comment: What platform are you using? Do `sort --help` and look for the version sort option.

Comment: I tried but i do not seem to have such option, just edited the post so you can see the sort --help I see in my unix

Comment: nice work around, however I'd have to add id after that because I need to match the file with other files, would you mind updating such that I remove id, and then sort, and then at the end I add the id prefix back.

Comment: Replacing `id` might over-match if other columns contain just numbers, if it doesn't work post the actual file and I will fix it.

Comment: thanks again.  It's odd, my unix version seems to be different from yours, sed -e also gives me an error. I just upvoted your answer, and had to accept Shawn solution since it works in my unix.

Answer (score 2):

As [sudo_o has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454464/sort-unix-file-by-id/13454516#13454516), the easiest would be to use `--version-sort` which does natural sorting of numbers that occur within text.

If your version of `sort` does not have that option, a hacky way to approach this would be to temporarily remove the "id" prefix before a sort, then replace them. Here's one way, using awk:

```
awk 'sub("^id", "", $4)' file.txt | sort -k4,4n | awk 'sub("^", "id", $4)'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `sort` supports it, you can also use the syntax F.C to use specific characters from a field.

This would sort on field 4, from chars 3 to 10, numerical value:

```
sort -bn -k 4.3,4.10 file
```

And this would sort on field 4, from chars 3 to end of field, numerical value:

```
sort -bn -k 4.3,4 file
```

Comment: F.C syntax seems to be a POSIX standard. You can also see http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/sort/